# Real-time updates for friends change only

Tags: facebook-graph-api, real-time

Using [Facebook real-time updates](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) I want to get notifications when and user (of my application) has connected with another (not necessarily of my application). It looks logical to subscribe using **object="user"** with **fields="friends"** which I did. The problem is the amount of notifications I'm getting (too many): it looks like I'm notified not only when an user connects/disconnects with another. Is it possible to get notifications ONLY for these types of events?

Thank,
George

Comment: How many users? I realize that, and ask to test 10 of my friends to install. I have about 500 requests in 2 weeks.

Comment: The application has a few hundreds of thousands of users and I'm getting around 3 notifications per minute each with around 30 users. In your case it also looks a lot of notifications: did your 10 friends have 500 changes of their friends list in 2 weeks?

Comment: Yes, I check every response and calculate updates (unfriends and friends) of my friends. And every time my apps users (or them) add or delete someone - facebook send me request.